# parse a csv into python dictionaries by structured range

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I've got a csv file that has ranges of information dumped into rows and comma separated.  Each line is a separate row, and the recordset is 'bookended' by rows that say startrecord (with an unique id) and stoprecord (matching id).  The data between the record bookmarks various, no there is some repeatability.

```
StartRecord, ID
name, value, other
name, value,value,value
EndRecord, ID
StartRecord, ID
name, value, other
something, another, another, something new, different
EndRecord, ID
StartRecord, ID
various, name, value, name, value, other
EndRecord, ID
```

I'm reading in the records using csv reader and iterating the rows.  How can I capture the data between and startrecord and endrecord into separate dictionary objects (in this example, I'd have 3 records)?

Comment: How is the CSV file created? If it was possible to create the file so its a line per ID
You could split on new line as you read it

Comment: @Travis - The csv is created from an export program, with a fixed format. It's an older application and not extensible.

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` statement should be helpful here. Try this.

```
import csv

dict = {}
current_id = ''

with open('filename.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        if row[0] == 'StartRecord':
            current_id = row[1]
            dict[row[1]] = []
            continue
        if row[0] == 'EndRecord':
            continue
        dict[current_id].append(row)

print(dict)
```

Edit: I realised that you may need to modify the `delimiter` argument if your csv file has spaces after the commas like in your example.